# Error DOCTRINE migración base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

veréis estoy atascado en un error que no consigo corregir. Básicamente he creado una base de datos con doctrine="php bin/console doctrine:database:create" y he ejecutado la migración ="php bin/console make:migration", lo que pasa es que me peta al migrar archivos con **[php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
]**

[image: error SQLSTATE 42000]
No sé que error de SYNTAX puede haber si estoy utilizando el framework de Symphony y literalmente no he escrito nada aun!!!!

Muchas gracias por la ayuda....

Pd: Por si sirve de algo, la línea de la migración que creo que peta:

```
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
```

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el problema, por si alguien en el futuro se lo encuentra:

1 ) Al parecer el problema venía de que mi server_version: mysql-5.5 tenía problemas con el tipo JSON

2) Instalé mariaDB versión 10.4 (tiene que ser superior a 10.2 creo)

3)En doctrine.yaml:

- Sustituí "server_version=5.7" por "server_version=mariadb-10.4.8"

4) Volví a crear mi database e hice las migraciones y todo OK!

PD: Si al instalar mariaDB os pone que el puerto 3306 está en uso (por mysql), básicamente asignad otro puerto y luego en .env meted ese puerto.

Un saludo,